# Wrap children inside view React native

Tags: css, reactjs, react-native, flexbox, react-native-flexbox

I have the following code:

```
renderActionButtons(actionButtons){

   let actionButtonsContent = actionButtons.map((button, i) => {
      return <TouchableHighlight key={i} onPress={() => {this.updateConversation(button);}} style={globalStyle.actionButton} underlayColor='#f1f1f1'>
      <View key={i}>
        <Text style= {globalStyle.actionButtonText}>{ button }</Text>
      </View> 
      </TouchableHighlight>                           
    })
    return actionButtonsContent
  }

  renderConversations(){
    let conversationContent = this.state.conversationArray.map((convObj, i) => {
      return <View key={i} style={[globalStyle.conversationContainer,globalStyle.shadow,convObj.directionClass]}>
        <Text style= {[globalStyle.conversationText,convObj.directionTextClass]}>{ convObj.text }</Text>
        <View style= {globalStyle.actionButtonsContainer}>
          { this.renderActionButtons(convObj.actionButtons) }
        </View>
      </View>                            
    })
    return conversationContent
  }
```

This is to render the following view:
[image]

I'm trying to wrap those pills inside the white container. 
Following are the styles I have used:

```
 conversationContainer:{
    maxWidth:310,
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    borderBottomRightRadius: 10,
    borderTopRightRadius: 10,
    borderBottomLeftRadius: 0,
    borderTopLeftRadius: 10,
    padding: 10,
    marginTop: 10
  },
actionButtonsContainer:{
    flex:1,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    paddingTop: 10
  },
  actionButton:{
    backgroundColor:primaryRed,
    borderRadius:30,
    padding: 7,
    marginRight: 10
  },
  actionButtonText:{
    color:'white',
    fontSize:12,
    alignSelf: 'center'
  },
```

How can I wrap the child Elements inside the parent element so that it doesn't overflow like show in picture ?

Comment: thank you sooraj for posting this. I've been spending so much time trying to get a row of buttons flex wrapped, so your question and the answer helped me

Answer (score 24, accepted):

With flexbox, you have the [flexWrap](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/layout-props.html#flexwrap) property, it defines whether the flex items are forced in a single line or can be wrapped. By default it's set to `nowrap`. Set it to `wrap`:

```
actionButtonsContainer:{
  flex:1,
  flexDirection: 'row',
  flexWrap: 'wrap',
  paddingTop: 10
},
```

Comment: Maybe something has changed over the years. `flexWrap` isn't working for me.

Comment: It should be ok, I think you have something that disables it.